# Ho to paste stored components properties values to another project and also how to format the properties in string[]?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In one project I have editor window script with the copy :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;

public class EditorWindowCopyComponentsData : EditorWindow
{
    [MenuItem("GameObject/Copy Components", false, 20)]
    public static void CopyComponents(MenuCommand command)
    {
        var go = Selection.activeGameObject;//command.context as GameObject;
        var components = go.GetComponents<Component>().ToList();
        foreach (Transform child in go.transform)
        {
            foreach (Component component in child.GetComponents<Component>())
            {
                components.Add(component);
            }
        }
        var serializedData = new string[components.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < components.Count; i++)
        {
            // Type-AssemblyQualifiedName : Json-Serialized-Data
            serializedData[i] = components[i].GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName + ":" + EditorJsonUtility.ToJson(components[i]);
        }
        EditorGUIUtility.systemCopyBuffer = string.Join("\n", serializedData);
    }
}
```

When I'm using a break point and put the mouse over the serializedData I see the 6 components properties and values of the properties but they are format different for example screenshot of serializedData[0] content :

[image: serializedData[0] content]

And if I'm copying all the serializedData that is in the CopyBuffer to empty notepad text file :

[image: Notepad]

And I want somehow to format the serializedData to looks like the components for example components[0] content :

[image: components[0] content]

So when paste whats in CopyBuffer for example to Notepad the format should be for example :

```
Component[0]
Properties :

childCount = 1
eulerAngles = "(12.8, 179.1, 0.0)"
```

And so on...
Then

```
Component[1]
Properties :

etc....= 45546
etc property = fsdfsdf
```

This format like it's in the components
And to add for an option also to add sub properties to the Copybuffer or to the format for example on the property eulerAngles on it's left side there is a small arrow and if you put the mouse on it it will show some deep level more properties and values so as an option to format and how them too in the CopyBuffer when copy the components.

Second problem is when make a paste in the other project :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using System;

public class EditorWindowCopyComponentsData : EditorWindow
{
    [MenuItem("GameObject/Paste Components", false, 21)]
    public static void PasteComponents(MenuCommand command)
    {
        var go = Selection.activeGameObject;//command.context as GameObject;
        var serializedData = EditorGUIUtility.systemCopyBuffer.Split('\n');
        char[] splitter = { ':' };
        foreach (var data in serializedData)
        {
            var typeAndJson = data.Split(splitter, 2);
            var type = Type.GetType(typeAndJson[0]);
            if (type.FullName == "UnityEngine.Transform") // only 1 transform
            {
                EditorJsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(typeAndJson[1], go.transform);
            }
            else
            {
                EditorJsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(typeAndJson[1], go.AddComponent(type));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It will not put the childs components as childs of 'go' like when copy.
In the copy I loop also over the child components and add them to the components List and copy them too :

```
foreach (Transform child in go.transform)
            {
                foreach (Component component in child.GetComponents<Component>())
                {
                    components.Add(component);
                }
            }
```

But how can I add them in the same order and place as childs also when paste it ?